# Get value from task resources

Tags: vba, macros, ms-project

I want to make macro that get the values of the task resources ("Erträge" and "Kosten") and set these values to variables so I can use them to calculate things 
[image: t]

I am using "For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks" to do the same with all Tasks my only Problem is that I don't know how to get this values from "Ressourcenamen".

Example code for my calculation:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim E As Double
Dim A As Double
Dim test As Double

For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks

test = E + A + test 

Debug.Print test

Next t
End Sub
```

"E" and "A" should be the resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out myself

```
A = ActiveProject.Tasks(t).Assignments(1).Cost
E = ActiveProject.Tasks(t).Assignments(2).Cost
```